# Area of the mask RCNN

Tags: python, project

I created my own dataset, with images of waste in landfield, using python. Mask RCNN creates a polygon mask over that object i want to, But I'm not able to find the area of the masks.

I need to find the area in red, in the image,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLH1y.jpg) of the mask to finish my project and i need some help.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example